# How to get variable value of applescript in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos, applescript

```
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init] ;

 NSAppleEventDescriptor *eventDescriptor;
 NSAppleScript *script ;
 NSString* source ;
 NSDictionary* errorDic ;

 source=@"tell application \"iTunes\" \n"
 @"set tname to name of track 1 of playlist 1 \n"
 @"set tartist to artist of track 1 of playlist 1 \n"
 @"set talbum to album of track 1 of playlist 1 \n"
 @"set ttime to time of track 1 of playlist 1 \n"
 @"set tbitrate to bit rate of track 1 of playlist 1 \n"
 @"set tsize to size of track 1 of playlist 1 \n"
 @"set trating to rating of track 1 of playlist 1 \n"
 @"end tell";

 script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
 eventDescriptor = [script executeAndReturnError:&errorDic];
 NSString* frontUrl = [eventDescriptor stringValue];
 NSLog(frontUrl);

 /*NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc]init];
 [alert setMessageText:frontUrl];
 [alert runModal];
 [alert release];*/

 [pool release] ;
```

NSlog only display a track rating. How to get value of tname,tartist,talbum,etc ?'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applescript returns the value of the last statement executed. In this case, that's `trating`. Put a statement at the end that contains all the values (say, a list).

Comment: I tried to change to

tell application "iTunes"

 set mydata to get {persistent ID, name, artist, album} of track 1 of playlist 1

 get mydata

end tell

but the result is null

Comment: Just return `{ tname, tartist, talbum, ttime, tbitrate, tsize, trating }`. Once you get that working, you may want to try returning and handling a record instead of a list, so that you aren't relying on the indexes agreeing between the AppleScript code and the Cocoa code.